# Pyping install error

Tags: python, pip, ping

I want to install pyping with `pip install pyping` but there are error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
   ....
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: try with `pip install --upgrade pip` then `pip install pyping`, and try with `sudo`. Also try `pip install -U pyping`

Comment: the rest of the eroor ????

Comment: @BenyaminJafari issued the same error when input that command

Comment: @Inder `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'`

Comment: It's not even upgrading pip u r saying???

Comment: @Inder yes, issued the same error

Comment: try this :https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/

Comment: download this :https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
run python get-pip.py
It will upgrade pip